# facebook page id using java script sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

With the following code when I am trying to fetch facebook page id, it is giving me only code,algorithm,issued_at and userid values. There is no page id exist. Am I doing any thing wrong here?

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true  
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response any time this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            //var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;                                                               
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //FB.login();
        } else {
            //FB.login();
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

   function getrequest() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {      
            var sq = FB.getAuthResponse()['signedRequest'];               
            var data = sq.split('.')[1];
            var dt = JSON.parse(atob(data));
            var cd = JSON.stringify(dt);
            $('#errmsg').text(cd);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
getrequest();
});
```

Comment: Is this a page tab application? You need to read the page id from the signed request in the POST var - this happens server-side - not in the JS

Comment: Yes it is page tab application. Can you explain in terms of code.

Comment: Presently I am working with asp.net mvc 3.0, where in the default index action I have tried to fetch signed request like this, HttpContext.Request.QueryString["signed_request"] but it is giving me null value.

Comment: I'm not an ASP coder - but I think you need to get it from HttpContext.Request.Form - it is a POST not a GET

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!! I got it using Request.Param. You saved my day.